# What is the subject of the sentence, "The term rules includes the following: <list>"?

Tags: grammaticality

I am trying to determine if I should use the singular "includes" or the plural "include" depending on whether "term" or "rules" is the subject.

Comment: Or rather, "The term 'rules' includes the following: <list>"

Comment: Well, are there quotation marks or not?

Answer (score 1):

The simple subject of the sentence is "rules" which is plural.  "The" and "term" are modifiers.

"The term rules include the following:"

If you have quotes around rules then "term" becomes the subject.  Rules is a kind of appositive.

"The term 'rules' includes the following ideas / restrictions / prohibitions / guidelines:"

I have changed your sentence to make it a bit more clear.  I would try and rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

In this sentence, 'rules' is the subject, and it is plural. Also, "rules" must be plural since a list of rules follows the colon.  In this sentence, 'term' is an adjective for the noun 'rules' which eliminates 'term' as a subject.  However, another contextual meaning could exist for this word combination, but the subject (possibly 'term rules') would still be plural in nature.

The plural form of the verb 'include' should be used in this sentence.

It should read:  "The term rules include the following: (list)"